# Inserting Comparator classes in a Java class

Tags: java, comparator

I need to add comparator classes to a class I have representing a Card in Java. One comparator (compareAscending) sorts the cards into ascending order, sorted first by suit and then rank (i.e. suit order spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs, then by value). The second comparator (compareRank) sorts into ascending order of rank, i.e. all the twos first then all the threes. .

Suit and rank are both enums and the code for them is below

```
enum Rank {

    TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10), ACE(11);

    private int value;

    Rank(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Rank getPrevious() {
        return values()[ordinal() > 0 ? ordinal() - 1 : 0];
    }

}

enum Suit {

    CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;

    public static Suit randomSuit() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return values()[random.nextInt(values().length)];
    }
}
```

Ive never used comparator classes before, so was wondering if someone could explain how I go about inserting them? Are they the same as making the class comparable (which it is)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make a Card class with those compare methods. Just use `.ordinal()` to get the enum's position in the enum array and compare them like that.

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial. Why *specifically* can you not write the code yourself?

Comment: You don't need to "insert" them, just make two `Comparator` implementations, and pass an instance of that Comparator to the sort function for it to use.

Comment: You are working with java 8, right? Because java 8 `Comparator` can do things quite compact, and combine things. Having Suite and Rank in a Card type would make sense. For different games different comparators might make sense.

Answer (score 4):

A `Comparator<Card>` is more or less the same as implementing `Comparable<Card>`:

```
a.compareTo(b)
```

becomes

```
comparator.compare(a, b);
```

You can even use one of the comparators you define for your `compareTo` method to avoid duplicating code:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    public static final Comparator<Card> COMPARE_ASCENDING = (a, b) -> { /* compare here */ };
    public static final Comparator<Card> COMPARE_DESCENDING = (a, b) -> { /* compare here */ };

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card other) {
        // Ascending is the "default" sort:
        return COMPARE_ASCENDING.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
List<Card> cards = ...;
Collections.sort(cards); // #1
Collections.sort(cards, Card.COMPARE_ASCENDING); // #2, same as #1
Collections.sort(cards, Card.COMPARE_DESCENDING); // #3
```

You can also add other common comparators, such as ones that consider Aces as low cards instead of high cards. Games can also implement their own game-specific comparators, but those wouldn't go in your `Card` class.